# Tikz: Compare coordinates of two nodes to determine coordinates of next node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

I am currently making a flowchart to describe the dependencies of modules in an algorithm. There are several branches and these reconnect at some point. Because my algorithm is still changing, the flowchart will be updated.

I would like to have the node (Target_02) reconnecting the branches to depend on x-coordinate of the pre-split node (Origin) and the y-coordinate of two final nodes in each branch by taking the lowest of y-values between node (Operation_01cc) and node (Target_01a).

Or: how do I compare coordinates between two nodes?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={5pt 5pt 5pt 5pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
>={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
% Specifications for style of nodes:
base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black,
    minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm,
    text centered, font=\sffamily},
Table/.style = {base, bottom color=yellow!70, top color=white},
TableTarget/.style = {base, bottom color=green!75!black!70, top color=white},
AnOperation/.style = {base, bottom color=gray!70, top color=white},
finalTarget/.style = {base, bottom color=blue!70, top color=white, draw=blue},
}
\begin{document}    
% Drawing part, node distance is 1.5 cm and every node
% is prefilled with white backgroun
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,
every node/.style={fill=white, font=\sffamily}, align=center, scale=0.8]

\node (Origin)          [Table]{00};                                                        

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% PREPPING SOURCE. %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\node (Operation_00b)   [AnOperation, above of=Origin] {};                          
\node(Source_00b)       [Table, left of=Operation_00b, xshift=-3 cm] {};    
\node (Operation_00a)   [AnOperation, above of=Operation_00b] {};   
\node(Source_00a)       [Table, left of=Operation_00a, xshift=-3 cm] {};                                
\node (Source_Table)    [Table, above of=Operation_00a] {};                 

\draw[->]               (Source_Table)              -- (Operation_00a);   
\draw[->]               (Source_00a)    -- (Operation_00a);                         
\draw[->]               (Operation_00a)         -- (Operation_00b);
\draw[->]               (Source_00b)        -- (Operation_00b);                         
\draw[->]               (Operation_00b)         -- (Origin);                                


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% BRANCH 01a. %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\node (Operation_01aa)  [AnOperation, below of=Origin, xshift=-9cm] {};
\node (Source_01aa)     [Table, left of=Operation_01aa, xshift=-3cm] {};    
\node (Operation_01ab)  [AnOperation, below of=Operation_01aa] {};                                                                      
\node (Source_01ab)     [Table, left of=Operation_01ab, xshift = -3cm] {};  
\node (Operation_00ac)  [AnOperation, below of=Operation_01ab] {};
\node (Source_01ac)     [Table, left of=Operation_00ac, xshift = -3cm]  {};
\node (Target_01a)      [TableTarget, below of=Operation_00ac]      {01ac}; 

\draw[->]               (Source_01aa) -- (Operation_01aa);                                      
\draw[->]               (Origin) -| (Operation_01aa);                   
\draw[->]               (Source_01ab) -- (Operation_01ab);                                      
\draw[->]               (Operation_01aa) -- (Operation_01ab);                                   
\draw[->]               (Source_01ac) -- (Operation_00ac);
\draw[->]               (Operation_01ab) -- (Operation_00ac);
\draw[->]               (Operation_00ac) -- (Target_01a);                               


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% BRANCH 01c. %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\node (Operation_01ca)  [AnOperation, below of=Origin, xshift=9cm]{};
\node (Source_01ca)     [Table,left of=Operation_01ca, xshift=-3cm] {}; 
\node (Target_01ca)     [TableTarget, below of=Operation_01ca]   {}; 
\node (Operation_01cb)  [AnOperation,below of=Target_01ca]    {};   
\node (Target_01cb)     [TableTarget, below of=Operation_01cb]  {}; 
\node(Operation_01cc)   [AnOperation, below of=Target_01cb] {01cc}; 

\draw[->]               (Source_01ca) --  (Operation_01ca);                                     
\draw[->]               (Origin) -| (Operation_01ca);       
\draw[->]               (Operation_01ca) -- (Target_01ca);      
\draw[->]               (Target_01ca) -- (Operation_01cb);      
\draw[->]               (Operation_01cb) -- (Target_01cb);      
\draw[->]               (Target_01cb) -- (Operation_01cc);                              

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% RECOMBINE BRANCHES %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  

\node (Target_02)   [TableTarget, below of=Operation_01cc, xshift=-9cm] {};

\draw[->]               (Operation_01cc) |- (Target_02);        
\draw[->]               (Target_01a) |- (Target_02);                            

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% FURTHER OPERATION %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\node(Operation_03a)    [AnOperation, below of=Target_02] {};                                       
\node(Source_03a)       [Table, left of=Operation_03a, xshift=-3cm] {};                             
\node(Operation_03b)    [AnOperation, below of=Operation_03a] {};       
\node(Target_03b)       [TableTarget, below of=Operation_03b] {};
\node(future)           [TableTarget, below of=Target_03b] {};

\draw[->]               (Operation_03b) -- (Target_03b);  
\draw[->]               (Operation_03a) -- (Operation_03b); 
\draw[->]               (Source_03a) -- (Operation_03a);    
\draw[->]               (Target_02) -- (Operation_03a); 
\draw[->]               (Target_03b) -- (future);   

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% THE FINAL TABLE %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\node(finalTarget)  [finalTarget, below of=future]  {};

\draw[->]           (future) -- (finalTarget);  
\draw[->]           (Origin)  -- (Target_02);                       

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice MWE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract the coordinates, but it is probably easier to use the `fit` library to create a node around the relevant operation and target nodes.

I'd also recommend the `positioning` library. `below of=` etc. is deprecated.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,fit,positioning}
\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
  base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  Table/.style = {base, bottom color=yellow!70, top color=white},
  TableTarget/.style = {base, bottom color=green!75!black!70, top color=white},
  AnOperation/.style = {base, bottom color=gray!70, top color=white},
  finalTarget/.style = {base, bottom color=blue!70, top color=white, draw=blue},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, node distance=1.5cm, every node/.style={fill=white, font=\sffamily}, align=center, scale=0.8]

  \node (Origin)          [Table]{00};

  \node (Operation_00b)   [AnOperation, above of=Origin] {};
  \node(Source_00b)       [Table, left of=Operation_00b, xshift=-3 cm] {};
  \node (Operation_00a)   [AnOperation, above of=Operation_00b] {};
  \node(Source_00a)       [Table, left of=Operation_00a, xshift=-3 cm] {};
  \node (Source_Table)    [Table, above of=Operation_00a] {};

  \draw               (Source_Table)              -- (Operation_00a);
  \draw               (Source_00a)    -- (Operation_00a);
  \draw               (Operation_00a)         -- (Operation_00b);
  \draw               (Source_00b)        -- (Operation_00b);
  \draw               (Operation_00b)         -- (Origin);

  \node (Operation_01aa)  [AnOperation, below of=Origin, xshift=-9cm] {};
  \node (Source_01aa)     [Table, left of=Operation_01aa, xshift=-3cm] {};
  \node (Operation_01ab)  [AnOperation, below of=Operation_01aa] {};
  \node (Source_01ab)     [Table, left of=Operation_01ab, xshift = -3cm] {};
  \node (Operation_00ac)  [AnOperation, below of=Operation_01ab] {};
  \node (Source_01ac)     [Table, left of=Operation_00ac, xshift = -3cm]  {};
  \node (Target_01a)      [TableTarget, below of=Operation_00ac]      {01ac};

  \draw               (Source_01aa) -- (Operation_01aa);
  \draw               (Origin) -| (Operation_01aa);
  \draw               (Source_01ab) -- (Operation_01ab);
  \draw               (Operation_01aa) -- (Operation_01ab);
  \draw               (Source_01ac) -- (Operation_00ac);
  \draw               (Operation_01ab) -- (Operation_00ac);
  \draw               (Operation_00ac) -- (Target_01a);

  \node (Operation_01ca)  [AnOperation, below of=Origin, xshift=9cm]{};
  \node (Source_01ca)     [Table,left of=Operation_01ca, xshift=-3cm] {};
  \node (Target_01ca)     [TableTarget, below of=Operation_01ca]   {};
  \node (Operation_01cb)  [AnOperation,below of=Target_01ca]    {};
  \node (Target_01cb)     [TableTarget, below of=Operation_01cb]  {};
  \node(Operation_01cc)   [AnOperation, below of=Target_01cb] {01cc};

  \draw               (Source_01ca) --  (Operation_01ca);
  \draw               (Origin) -| (Operation_01ca);
  \draw               (Operation_01ca) -- (Target_01ca);
  \draw               (Target_01ca) -- (Operation_01cb);
  \draw               (Operation_01cb) -- (Target_01cb);
  \draw               (Target_01cb) -- (Operation_01cc);

  \node (f) [inner sep=0pt, draw=none, fill=none, fit=(Operation_01cc) (Target_01a)] {};
  \node (Target_02)   [TableTarget, below=of Origin |- f.south] {};

  \draw               (Operation_01cc) |- (Target_02);
  \draw               (Target_01a) |- (Target_02);

  \node(Operation_03a)    [AnOperation, below of=Target_02] {};
  \node(Source_03a)       [Table, left of=Operation_03a, xshift=-3cm] {};
  \node(Operation_03b)    [AnOperation, below of=Operation_03a] {};
  \node(Target_03b)       [TableTarget, below of=Operation_03b] {};
  \node(future)           [TableTarget, below of=Target_03b] {};

  \draw               (Operation_03b) -- (Target_03b);
  \draw               (Operation_03a) -- (Operation_03b);
  \draw               (Source_03a) -- (Operation_03a);
  \draw               (Target_02) -- (Operation_03a);
  \draw               (Target_03b) -- (future);

  \node(finalTarget)  [finalTarget, below of=future]  {};

  \draw           (future) -- (finalTarget);
  \draw           (Origin)  -- (Target_02);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: a fitting solution, possibly]